# Bogus values returned by `ToPixels`

Tags: highcharts

While I'm dynamically building a chart, I need to add some SVG elements in it. To do so, I convert some coordinates into pixels coordinates via `ToPixels`.

However if I call `ToPixels` on my axes before it is being rendered, the value I'm getting is invalid. It should be around 800 and I'm getting values around 33000.

I have a workaround which is to call `redraw` before I call `ToPixels` but I don't think I should have to do that.

Comment: 1) need a fiddle or other live example that demonstrates the problem 2) Are you saying that you're calling `toPixels` on an element that has not yet been rendered? If so...I don't see how there could be an expectation to return a valid result.

Comment: When do you call toPixels()? Add the code/fiddle.